# Debugger for Code::Blocks + Arduino

Tags: debugging

I am not very experienced in this, but I was wondering if Code::Blocks has a way of getting a debugger that runs for Arduino chips, specifically. I understand there is Arduino IDE for but does it allow debugging specific to those microcontrollers (Amtel and such)?

Comment: This is for Mac between.

Comment: The arduino IDE does not support debugging on chip, and it will take additional hardware to do it (like a JTAG). I don't know if Code::Blocks has any support for this kind on chip debugging though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in on-board debugging or off-board debugging, you will need a programmer/debugger. I would recommend the Atmel [AVR Dragon](http://www.atmel.com/tools/avrdragon.aspx). Atmel AVR Dragon uses the Atmel Studio 6.2, which is a great IDE.

[image: AVR Dragon]

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Code blocks does not currently have an Arduino debugger. The Arduino IDE does not have a debugger.

There is an Arduino debugger in Atmel Studio using the Visual Micro plugin.

That said, you have to use Ms Windows to use Atmel Studio which might not be available to you.

The Visual Micro debugger is simple and uses usb so does not require additional hardware but as your experience grows you might also like to progress to fully blown hardware debug using the native Atmel Studio Tools

[Visual Micro debug in Atmel Studio](http://www.visualmicro.com/page/Debugging-for-Arduino.aspx)

[Atmel Studio Download](http://www.atmel.com/tools/atmelstudio.aspx)

[image: Arduino usb debugger]

Comment: Can you suggest a hardware debugger to go with C::B?

Comment: I already answered that question so I am not sure what you are trying to achieve by asking it again. Two of us have tried to help you but you seem to want to ignore the answer?